# OneDrive SDK Authentication Issue in Console App

Tags: c#, onedrive

I am coding against [OneDrive SDK](https://dev.onedrive.com/sdks.htm) within a console application. I am having some trouble trying to authenticate properly. I am curious to see if anyone has done this before or could point me in the right direction?

#### Code so far:

```
 [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scopes = new[] {"onedrive.readonly", "wl.signin"};
        var msaAuthProvider = new MsaAuthenticationProvider(ClientId, "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf", scopes);

        msaAuthProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync();
    }
```

Whenever I run my debugger I see the property of `isAuthenticated` is set to `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the MSA Authentication only supports Desktop and Windows Mobile Apps as it needs UI to require user sign in which broke in your case because you have a console app. So the problem is to build a `IAuthenticationProvider` which set the `Authorization` header in request message like:

```
    public async Task AuthenticateRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", await GetAccessTokenFromSomeWhere());
    }
```

The `IAuthenticationProvider` interface defined in `Microsoft.Graph.Core` and you can pass it into OneDriveClient constructor so OneDriveClient will make request to OneDrive API for you.

Based on the information you have a console app, I would suggest you look at the code flow for [Microsoft OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/guides/authentication-oauth?view=bingads-13#authorizationcode) to get an access token and pass it to your authentication proivder.

I am not sure how you can get a `code` from the OAuth flow, but it seems doable if you fetch it in somewhere and pass it to your console app, then you can make POST request the the `code` you have to redeem an access token. I have searched for a while and don't find a good example of console app to get OAuth for Microsoft account, sorry. If you find a good way for console app to authentication, feel free to send a PR for  [MSAAuthenticator](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-dotnet-msa-auth-adapter/).

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look into this and see what I come up with

Answer (score 0):

I succesfully read files from an user without interaction using the [OAuth 2.0 Resource Owner Password grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) and raw HTTP requests.

There are [samples for authentication in daemon applications with application credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-netcore-daemon), but first we would need to know how the application was registered and if belongs to a directory in Azure or not because app permissions need to be granted by a directory admin.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29977015)